# Prestashop 1.7.8.6 multistore nginx rewrite rules

Tags: nginx, prestashop, multistore

I install the prestashop 1.7 as a multistore and write nginx rewrite rule as

```
location /shop-1/ {
  rewrite ^/shop-1/(.*)$ /$1 last;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location /shop-2/ {
  rewrite ^/shop-2/(.*)$ /$1 last;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

I follow the nginx conf file from https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/nginx/

Now the Q is Parent domain navigating correctly and showing images but multistore redirected corrected to [http://example.com/{shop-1](http://example.com/%7Bshop-1) or shop-2} but not showing the images on the multishop urls, getting nginx 404 error on multishop url but same image showing on a parent domain.

example:

http://example.com/shop-1/45-medium_default/skirt.jpg not showing the image

http://example.com/45-medium_default/skirt.jpg showing the image

Answer (score 0):

To explain what happened here I need to refer to nginx [request processing phases](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases), a subject not many people actually understand correctly.

Here is a set of rewrite rules being executed at the `NGX_HTTP_SERVER_REWRITE_PHASE`:

```
rewrite ^/(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
rewrite ^/c/([\w.-]+)/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1.jpg last;
```

As you can see, none of them matches the `/shop-1/45-medium_default/skirt.jpg` request URI. So on the next turn, during the `NGX_HTTP_FIND_CONFIG_PHASE` your `location /shop-1/ { ... }` will be selected to handle the request. Next, after `rewrite ^/shop-1/(.*)$ /$1 last;` rule being executed, your request URI will be rewritten to `/45-medium_default/skirt.jpg`, and due to the used `last` flag on the `rewrite` directive the `NGX_HTTP_FIND_CONFIG_PHASE` will be executed again. However the `NGX_HTTP_SERVER_REWRITE_PHASE` won't be executed again, and a new URI won't be rewritten according to those rules. What you should do instead is to place a rewrite rule at the `server` level **before** the ruleset for rewriting image requests:

```
rewrite ^/(?:shop-1|shop-2)(/.*) $1;
... image URIs rewrite rules here
```

Note that I don't use `last` (or `break`) flag for this rule since the rewrite rules chain should not be terminated after this rewrite will be triggered. None of those two locations that you show in your question will be needed at all.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation, time and efforts. I understood and its working now

Comment: If you find the answer workable and useful, you may consider to mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/tour#:~:text=The%20person%20who%20asked%20can%20mark%20one%20answer%20as%20%22accepted%22.) (however, there is no obligation to do it).